# Orange juice stain the brew bucket, or even worse?

Tags: mead, bucket

Hello fellow home brewers!

I am looking to begin an orange melomel tomorrow using this page as inspiration. After making some orange juice from the same oranges as the one's I will be using, I noticed that it already took a bit of extra effort to clean the plastic pitcher afterward.

Considering I am considering leaving 6+ gallons of orange juice and honey in a brew bucket for a month, I can't help but wonder if should instead just go straight to the glass carboy.

Should I have anything to worry about if I use the brew bucket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An extended soak of your brew bucket with warm cleanser and/or bleach or baking soda will help clear up your bucket post this ferment.  Its not something to worry about IMO.  My old buckets have definite stains from years of use but I've never had carry over flavor issues.  Its usually too dilute compared to the flavors of the next ferment.

Comment: I agree, there is nothing to worry about here. I have stains on all my buckets and carboys.

Comment: Thank you. Racked the orange mead to secondary yesterday. There's a little be of staining left over but other than that all is good.